# Connect to Azure Storage via Connection String

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

I have an Azure Storage (StorageV2), and I want to connect and upload files via Powershell.

However, I want to use the **Connection String** (which contains a long secret key). So people without a Microsoft account should be able to use the script.

There is the command `Connect-AzAccount`, but for this, it seems you need to have a Microsoft account.

So how is it possible to connect and upload just with the Connection String and without having a Microsoft account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each Cmdlet in [`Az.Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-8.0.0) module expects a `-Context` parameter. You can use [`New-AzStorageContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-8.0.0) Cmdlet to set that context and pass that context to the Cmdlet (e.g. for uploading blob).

If you have the connection string for your storage account, you would create a context like:

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString "your-storage-account-connection-string"
```

and use it like the following:

```
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $ctx ...rest of the parameters
```